# Errors from context when running trie dictionary from cs50/pset5 speller through valgrind

Tags: c, malloc, valgrind, cs50

I'm working through Harvard's CS50 pset5 in which you're tasked with uploading a dictionary into a data structure of your choice and then spell checking given texts.

I've decided to go with a trie this time and it's spell checking correctly with no memory leaks.

However, running `valgrind -v ./speller texts/lalaland.txt` seems to return 9 errors from context.

I can't seem to figure out what exactly is the problem here given that there's no memory leak.

```
==5897== 
==5897== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5897==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5897==   total heap usage: 367,084 allocs, 367,084 frees, 82,227,504 bytes allocated
==5897== 
==5897== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==5897== 
==5897== ERROR SUMMARY: 9913647 errors from 9 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==5897== 
==5897== 1 errors in context 1 of 9:
==5897== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5897==    at 0x422434: unload_node (dictionary2.c:28)
==5897==    by 0x42362C: unload (dictionary2.c:170)
==5897==    by 0x421564: main (speller.c:152)
==5897==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==5897==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5897==    by 0x422E91: load (dictionary2.c:104)
==5897==    by 0x420992: main (speller.c:40)
==5897== 
==5897== 
==5897== 216 errors in context 2 of 9:
==5897== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5897==    at 0x422B80: check (dictionary2.c:73)
==5897==    by 0x421363: main (speller.c:112)
==5897==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==5897==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5897==    by 0x423216: load (dictionary2.c:131)
==5897==    by 0x420992: main (speller.c:40)
==5897== 
==5897== 
==5897== 221 errors in context 3 of 9:
==5897== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5897==    at 0x422434: unload_node (dictionary2.c:28)
==5897==    by 0x422534: unload_node (dictionary2.c:30)
==5897==    by 0x42362C: unload (dictionary2.c:170)
==5897==    by 0x421564: main (speller.c:152)
==5897==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==5897==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5897==    by 0x423216: load (dictionary2.c:131)
==5897==    by 0x420992: main (speller.c:40)
==5897== 
==5897== 
==5897== 739 errors in context 4 of 9:
==5897== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5897==    at 0x4213E7: main (speller.c:119)
==5897==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==5897==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5897==    by 0x423216: load (dictionary2.c:131)
==5897==    by 0x420992: main (speller.c:40)
==5897== 
==5897== 
==5897== 739 errors in context 5 of 9:
==5897== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5897==    at 0x4213C0: main (speller.c:119)
==5897==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==5897==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5897==    by 0x423216: load (dictionary2.c:131)
==5897==    by 0x420992: main (speller.c:40)
==5897== 
==5897== 
==5897== 739 errors in context 6 of 9:
==5897== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5897==    at 0x422DD5: check (dictionary2.c:83)
==5897==    by 0x421363: main (speller.c:112)
==5897==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==5897==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5897==    by 0x423216: load (dictionary2.c:131)
==5897==    by 0x420992: main (speller.c:40)
==5897== 
==5897== 
==5897== 9185 errors in context 7 of 9:
==5897== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5897==    at 0x422434: unload_node (dictionary2.c:28)
==5897==    by 0x422534: unload_node (dictionary2.c:30)
==5897==    by 0x422534: unload_node (dictionary2.c:30)
==5897==    by 0x42362C: unload (dictionary2.c:170)
==5897==    by 0x421564: main (speller.c:152)
==5897==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==5897==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5897==    by 0x423216: load (dictionary2.c:131)
==5897==    by 0x420992: main (speller.c:40)
==5897== 
==5897== 
==5897== 367081 errors in context 8 of 9:
==5897== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5897==    at 0x423205: load (dictionary2.c:127)
==5897==    by 0x420992: main (speller.c:40)
==5897==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==5897==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5897==    by 0x422E91: load (dictionary2.c:104)
==5897==    by 0x420992: main (speller.c:40)
==5897== 
==5897== 
==5897== 9534726 errors in context 9 of 9:
==5897== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5897==    at 0x422434: unload_node (dictionary2.c:28)
==5897==    by 0x422534: unload_node (dictionary2.c:30)
==5897==    by 0x422534: unload_node (dictionary2.c:30)
==5897==    by 0x422534: unload_node (dictionary2.c:30)
==5897==    by 0x42362C: unload (dictionary2.c:170)
==5897==    by 0x421564: main (speller.c:152)
==5897==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==5897==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5897==    by 0x423216: load (dictionary2.c:131)
==5897==    by 0x420992: main (speller.c:40)
==5897== 
==5897== ERROR SUMMARY: 9913647 errors from 9 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

dictionary2.c :

```
// Implements a dictionary's functionality

#include "dictionary.h"

// Define node to be used in hashtable
typedef struct node
{
    bool is_word;
    struct node *children[27];
}
node;

// Define root
node *root;

// Global variable to track word count
unsigned int word_count = 0;

// Global boolean to track whether dictionary was loaded or not
bool loaded = false;

// Helper function to unload trie nodes
void unload_node(node *firstnode)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++)
    {
        if (firstnode->children[i] != NULL)         // line 28
        {
            unload_node(firstnode->children[i]);    // line 30
        }
    }
    free(firstnode);
    return;
}


// Returns true if word is in dictionary else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    // TODO
    // Copy the word as word only has read access
    int length = strlen(word);
    char word_copy[length + 1];

    // Lowercase the word
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        word_copy[i] = tolower(word[i]);
    }

    // Nul terminate the string
    word_copy[length] = '\0';

    // Direct traversal pointer to root
    node *trav = root;

    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(word_copy); i < n; i++)
    {
        // Find numerical value of letter
        int alphanum;

        if (word_copy[i] == 39)
        {
            // If it is apostrophe, allocate last slot in array
            alphanum = 26;
        }
        else
        {
            alphanum = word_copy[i] - 97;
        }

        if (trav->children[alphanum] != NULL)       // line 73
        {
            trav = trav->children[alphanum];
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return trav->is_word;       // line 83
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // TODO

    // Open dictionary file
    FILE *inptr = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (inptr == NULL)
    {
        fclose(inptr);
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s.\n", dictionary);
        return 2;
    }

    // Scan through every word in dictionary and store into new node
    char wordBuffer[LENGTH + 1];

    // Malloc root node
    root = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));        // line 104

    while (fscanf(inptr, "%s", wordBuffer) != EOF)
    {
        // Create traversal pointer to the root
        node *trav = root;

        for (int i = 0, n = strlen(wordBuffer); i < n; i++)
        {
            // Find numeric value of letter
            int alphanum;

            if (wordBuffer[i] == 39)
            {
                // If it is apostrophe, allocate last space in children's array
                alphanum = 26;
            }
            else
            {
                alphanum = wordBuffer[i] - 97;
            }


            if (trav->children[alphanum] == NULL)       // line 127
            {

                // If node does not exist in array slot, allocate memory for new node
                trav->children[alphanum] = malloc(sizeof(node));        // line 131

            }

            // Redirect trav to child
            trav = trav->children[alphanum];

        }

        trav->is_word = true;

        word_count++;
    }

    fclose(inptr);
    loaded = true;

    return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
    // TODO
    if (loaded)
    {
        return word_count;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful else false
bool unload(void)
{
    // TODO
    node *trav = root;
    unload_node(trav);      // line 170
    return true;
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Since all of your errors are similar, I suggest removing all but one of the errors from your log.  Then annotate your code snippet with the line numbers mentioned in the error that you pick.  It's hard to debug without line numbers.

Comment: @fennel is there an easy way to add line numbers to my code snippet?

Comment: I'm not sure--I would just do it with inline comments for the line numbers called out in the specific error: `code... // Line number 29`

Comment: @fennel done! take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at context 8 of 9:

```
==5897== 367081 errors in context 8 of 9:
==5897== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5897==    at 0x423205: load (dictionary2.c:127)
==5897==    by 0x420992: main (speller.c:40)
==5897==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==5897==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5897==    by 0x422E91: load (dictionary2.c:104)
==5897==    by 0x420992: main (speller.c:40)
==5897==
```

> Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)

This means that you're doing `if (something)` without ever having initialized the `something`.  It's on line 127:

```
if (trav->children[alphanum] == NULL)
```

The value that is uninitialized must be `trav->children[alphanum]`.  Looking up through your loop, you see that you have

```
root = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));        // line 104
...
node *trav = root;
```

You malloced `root` but never actually set any values in it before trying to branch on it.  You should null out the entries in `root->children` before you use them.

---

You can also see this by looking at the second half of the error:

> Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation

It points back to line 104, telling you that you have an uninitialized value created by your allocation on line 104, which leads to the same conclusions.

Comment: So I iterated through every slot in the array `root->children` and assigned it to `NULL`. Seemed to get rid of one of the errors!

Comment: Great.  You should be able to follow a similar debug process for all of the other errors.  Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you.

Comment: i think my problem seems to be that in the last loop in check or load, i create a new node just to store `is_word = true` boolean that also has an empty uninitialised `children` array.

Answer (score 0):

To add onto @fennel 's answer, my `load` function seems to have a problem when it hits the last letter of a word in that it creates a new node just to signify the end of a word via `is_word = true`. That node's `children` array is also uninitialised which is the source of my errors.

```
while (fscanf(inptr, "%s", wordBuffer) != EOF)
    {
        // Create traversal pointer to the root
        node *trav = root;

        for (int i = 0, n = strlen(wordBuffer); i < n; i++)
        {
            // Find numeric value of letter
            int alphanum;

            if (wordBuffer[i] == 39)
            {
                // If it is apostrophe, allocate last space in children's array
                alphanum = 26;
            }
            else
            {
                alphanum = wordBuffer[i] - 97;
            }


            if (trav->children[alphanum] == NULL)       // line 127
            {

                // If node does not exist in array slot, allocate memory for new node
                trav->children[alphanum] = malloc(1, sizeof(node));        // line 131

            }

            // Redirect trav to child
            trav = trav->children[alphanum];

        }

        trav->is_word = true;

        word_count++;
    }
```

A simple fix would be to `calloc` instead of `malloc` as so:

```
if (trav->children[alphanum] == NULL)       // line 127
                {

                    // If node does not exist in array slot, allocate memory for new node
                    trav->children[alphanum] = calloc(1, sizeof(node));        // line 131

                }
```